# How do I write the correct css selector for a data-qe-id?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, constantcontact

How do I write the correct css selector for a data-qe-id?

```
<h2 data-qe-id="form-title" class="ctct-form-header">Sign up for updates!</h2>
<p data-qe-id="form-description" class="ctct-form-text">Get news from us in your inbox.</p>
```

This is specifically for modifying a Constant Contact email sign up box.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
h2[data-qe-id="form-title"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Using square brackets, you can refer to attributes and their values of any given DOM element.

Comment: This did not work in the Additional CSS section of wordpress (where I have had some success modifying part of the Constant Contact CSS code).  Maybe it would help to have the whole section of code?

Comment: <form class="ctct-form-custom" id="ctct_form_0" autocomplete="on" data-qe-id="form-data" action="https://abcdefg.com/?customize_changeset_uuid=2179b43a-7797-4a12-b20c-cf25f7a4415d&amp;customize_theme=abv&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" target="_self">
 <input type="hidden" name="customize_autosaved" value="on">
 <input type="hidden" name="customize_messenger_channel" value="preview-0">
 <input type="hidden" name="customize_changeset_uuid" value="2bd30b55-e6ea-431a-82f7-0fd1287718f5">
 <h2 data-qe-id="form-title" class="ctct-form-header">Sign up for updates!</h2>

Comment: <p data-qe-id="form-description" class="ctct-form-text">Get news in your inbox.</p>

Answer (score 1):

You an attribute selector. Like this:

```
[data-qe-id] {
    color: red;
}
```

or attribute with specific value...

```
[data-qe-id="form-title"] {
    color: red;
}
```

or attribute with a value that starts with a certain string...

```
[data-qe-id^="form"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: please see comment above...for some reason the custom CSS will not work with this in wordpress.

Comment: @KristinGuidi That is valid CSS, I have no idea where or how you are implementing it. Your question was _How do I write the correct css selector for a data-qe-id?_ Not _How to implement custom CSS in Wordpress_.

Comment: It looks like I needed to use the selector#ctct_form_0 [data-qe-id="form-description"] {color: red; }

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector then the data-qe-id:

```
    #ctct_form_0 [data-qe-id="form-description"]{
           color: red;}
```